# Assert Fails Even Though It Shouldn't

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have the following two asserts which are checking the `checked` attribute of a check box:

```
Assert.assertEquals(true, notificationCheck.getAttribute("checked").equals(true));
Assert.assertEquals(true, accessCheck.getAttribute("checked").equals(true));
```

I have setup a sort of debugging where it spits out to console the value of the `checked` attribute and they both say true.

The error that I am getting is below:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [false] but found [true]
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:494)
at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:123)
at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:286)
at org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:296)
at ui_Tests.ParticipantsPage_AddParticipant.participantPage_AddParticipant(ParticipantsPage_AddParticipant.java:305)
at ui_Tests.ParticipantsPage_AddParticipant.test_participantPage_AddParticipant_FF(ParticipantsPage_AddParticipant.java:315)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I removed the `.equals(true)` from both of the Asserts. 
Now I am getting the same error only now it says `expected [true] but found [true]`

Comment: How is the `notificationCheck.getAttribute()` object's `equals()` defined ?

Comment: Which of those two lines are failing?  Does `notificationCheck.getAttribute("checked")` return a boolean?  Does `accessCheck.getAttribute("checked")` return a boolean?

Comment: @parsifal that's what I thought.  Turns out testng reverses the expected/actual so that it's actual/expected.

Comment: @tieTYT - ah, my mistake, I didn't look closely enough to see the `testng` package name. I think you're probably on the right path in your comment, and the `getAttribute()` method returns a `String`.

Comment: maybe post all the test class? something else is the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you're mixing up data types... what type does notificationCheck.getAttribute("checked") return?? 
I suppose it does not return a Boolean but a String and that's why your test fails.
In that case you could try this:

```
Assert.assertEquals(true, notificationCheck.getAttribute("checked").equals("true"));
```

Even better:

```
Assert.assertEquals("true", notificationCheck.getAttribute("checked"));
```

Comment: Thank you, your `even better:` solution worked perfectly. That was the problem, the attribute was not returning a boolean.

Comment: No problem... but anyway, next time you want to assert something is actually a boolean true (not String "true" like in this case), just use the method http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean) not assertEquals(true, condition)

Comment: If you tried to use assertTrue(notificationCheck.getAttribute("checked")) you would have gotten a compiler error and you would've known right away what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

If its saying expected true and found true that means:
 The type might be different.
eg : what its getting is `boolean-true` and checking if its equal with `String-"true"` or vice versa.